# I moved my laptop while it was on. Will it damage my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, physical-damage

So I was inserting the charger pin in the charging port while a game was running from the hard drive and while inserting my laptop slided about an inch. Will it damage my hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The amount of movement is too small to damage a drive, and then additionally, almost all hard drives in the last decade park heads if moved so as to prevent damage.

You will not have an issue here.

Comment: Vote to Leave open this question. Link to review: https://superuser.com/review/close/1002216